# Parcelable implementation in Kotlin?

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, bundle

I have a listview implementation(**in HomeActivity.kt**) of user objects displaying specific data of the users from an ArrayList.
My setOnItemClickListener works fine and takes the user to another activity(**DetailsActivity.kt**) when any item is selected. I want to pass all the information of the selected user to display it in the **DetailsActicity.kt**. How do I implement **Parcelable** in KOTLIN to do this?

Here is my **HomeActivity.kt**

```
val sectors = arrayOf("Sector", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
        val sectorOption = findViewById<View>(R.id.sectorOption) as Spinner

        if(sectorOption != null){
            val sectorAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sectors)
            sectorOption.adapter = sectorAdapter
            sectorOption.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onItemSelected(
                    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                    view: View?,
                    position: Int,
                    id: Long
                ) {
                    if (parent != null) {
                        sect = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                        db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("sector", sect)
                            .get()
                            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                                if(task.isSuccessful){
                                    UserList.clear()
                                    for(document in task.result!!){
                                        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "test" + document.id + "=>" + document.data)

                                        UserList.add(User(document.get("Name").toString(), document.get("EmailID").toString(), document.get("sector").toString()))
                                    }
                                    UserDataAdapter = UserDataAdapter(ArrayList(UserList), applicationContext)
                                    listview.setAdapter(UserDataAdapter)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
                override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }
            }
        }        

        listview.setOnItemClickListener{parent, view, position, id ->
            val element = UserDataAdapter?.getItem(position)
            val intent = Intent(this, OrderActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

And this is my **User.kt** data class

```
data class User(val Name: String = "",
                 val sector: String = "",
                 val Address: String = "",
                 val Mobile: String = "",
                 val EmailID: String = ""
)
```

Comment: One code improvement. Instead of `val sectorOption = findViewById<View>(R.id.sectorOption) as Spinner` -> you can directly use `val sectorOption = findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.sectorOption)`

Comment: You will have to make your data class [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable). see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-an-object-from-one-activity-to-another-on-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: @mightyWOZ Thanks for the links to parcelable and serializable but I am not able to implement those in Kotlin as I can't find any reliable documentation or solution for that since most documentation and answers are in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use `@Parcelable` annotation from [Android Kotlin extensions plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable-implementations-generator).

It saves you writing boilerplate code and provides a way to customize serialization/deserialization via implementing `Parceler` instances.

Also you still have the option to implement the `Parcelable` interface the normal way with Kotlin: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Parcelable